# Lua Global Override

Tags: function, debugging, lua, overriding, global

I'm trying to figure out how to find the script that's calling a specific function when I globally override it. For example:

```
rawset(_G, 'print',
function()
    --check if xxx program is calling, then print a different way
end)
```

OR

```
_G.print = 
fucntion()
    --check if xxx program is calling, then print a different way
end
```

How do I figure out which script is calling print()?
I know I'm supposed to use the debug features of lua, but I'm not sure exactly what.

Comment: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-debug.getinfo

Comment: It should be pointed out that you may or may not be able to actually do what you want here since you may not have the information (like a name) that you may want to check about your calling function.

Comment: Etan, so there is no way for me to be able to do this? I tried debug.getinfo and it seems like there is no way for me to get information on the file that's calling the function.

Comment: Do you control loading of the script calling print? If you do, you could try altering its environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
old_print = print
print = function(...) 
    local calling_script = debug.getinfo(2).short_src
    old_print('Print called by: '..calling_script)
    old_print(...)
end
print('a','b')
print('x','c');
```

Result:

```
> dofile "test2.lua"
Print called by: test.lua
a       b
Print called by: test.lua
x       c
Print called by: test2.lua
a
```

I tested it with Lua 52, but i know that it also works with Lua50-3, so it should also work with Lua51.

Short summary:

```
local calling_script = debug.getinfo(2).short_src
```

It gives ALWAYS back the script where the function which calls the print has been defined. So be careful.. I don't exactly know what you want to do with this, so i can't give you an 100% exact solution, but this should lead you to the correct way!